# async with fs file is not saving

Tags: node.js, fs

I have this code:
(i need to use async because this function may be used multiple times per second, so file won't be saved without async)

```
var fs = require('fs').promises;
async function stater(amount){
   const file = await fs.readFile('stater.txt', function read(err, data) {
      content = Number(data);
      content +=Number(amount);    
      
      if(amount == "clear") content = 0;
      fs.writeFile('stater.txt', content);
      logger.trace("Stater added: " + amount)
   });
   await fs.writeFile('stater.txt', 'test');
}
stater(10000);
```

But after `stater(10000)` nothing seems to happen, no errors, but file is not changing. But it works without async, so why so?

Comment: Why are you using callbacks when you want to use promises?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you're using a callback for `fs.readFile()` which won't get called because you're using the Promise-based version.

You need to use promises all the way:

```
const data = await fs.readFile('stater.txt');
let content = Number(data);
content +=Number(amount);    
  
if(amount == "clear") content = 0;
await fs.writeFile('stater.txt', content);
logger.trace("Stater added: " + amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you declared `starter` function to be asynchronous. Just declaring it to be asynchronous is not enough. It should be called another (async) function and you should use the `await` keyword before it. You can also use IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).
Example:

```
var fs = require('fs').promises;
async function stater(amount){
   const file = await fs.readFile('stater.txt', function read(err, data) {
      content = Number(data);
      content +=Number(amount);    
      
      if(amount == "clear") content = 0;
      fs.writeFile('stater.txt', content);
      logger.trace("Stater added: " + amount)
   });
   await fs.writeFile('stater.txt', 'test');
}

(async () => {
  await stater(10000);
})();
```

Few other things I noticed:

1. Have you declared `content` variable somewhere?
2. Do you know that typeof `data` will be a string? `Number(string)` may not work as you intended.